# unable to start zabbix_server on OSX 10.9

Tags: log-files, mac-osx-server, zabbix, permissions

I followed the zabbix docs available on https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/doku.php?id=2.0/manual/installation/install **Installation from source**

I have the web part up and running and I get **Zabbix server is running: NO** as status message. I checked the log file and I see these two lines everytime I try to start the server:

```
zabbix_server [61503]: cannot create Semaphore: [13] Permission denied
zabbix_server [61503]: unable to create mutex for log file
```

Anybody familiar with semaphores on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I encountered, producing the same error, was that the web server runs as user _www and zabbix runs as user zabbix.  I installed via MacPorts and am using the default Apache server.  The semaphore is created with 660 permissions, so one or the other user is unable to access it.

```
% ipcs -s
IPC status from  as of Tue Jul 22 11:08:18 MDT 2014
T     ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP
Semaphores:
...
s 655368 0x7a03e3ce --ra-ra----     _www     _www
s 458761 0x7a03e2ed --ra-------     _www     _www
s 524298 0x7a03e559 --ra-ra----     _www     _www
s  65547 0x7a0312c8 --ra-------   zabbix   zabbix
```

Rather than mess with the semaphore creation or group membership, I patched the zabbix_server.init file and run zebbix as user _www.

```
*** /opt/local/share/zabbix/zabbix_server.init  2014-07-21 17:42:14.000000000 -0600
--- /opt/local/share/zabbix/zabbix_server.init.orig 2014-07-22 11:11:49.000000000 -0600
***************
*** 3,10 ****
  case "$1" in
      start)
    echo -n "Starting zabbix_server - 60s start delay for SQL server to load during boot"
!   #sleep 60
!         sudo -u _www /opt/local/sbin/zabbix/zabbix_server -c /opt/local/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
          ;;

      stop)
--- 3,10 ----
  case "$1" in
      start)
    echo -n "Starting zabbix_server - 60s start delay for SQL server to load during boot"
!   sleep 60
!         sudo -u zebbix /opt/local/sbin/zabbix/zabbix_server -c /opt/local/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
          ;;

      stop)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late accept ;) I have Zabbix Server 3.2 running stable for quite some time now...